# How can display an AdView at every n-th position in a listView

Tags: android, listview

I have the code below which works except it always hides atleast one real item in the listview because the ad displays at that position.

**Example of the problem:** I have a list of 4 times, and the adView is displaying at position 3. on the listview I can only see 3 times and the AdView, the 4th item does not get displayed

I played around with increasing the size of the adapter everytime I return an ad but it didn't work very well.

Any ideas?

```
public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyHolder holder = null;
        boolean showAd = proVersion == false && (position % 8 == k);
        if (showAd) {
            AdView adView = adList.get(position);
            if (adView == null) {
                AdView adViewNew = new AdView((Activity) context, AdSize.BANNER, context.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.adId));
                adViewNew.loadAd(Utils.getAdRequest("gps", lat, lng, keywords));
                adList.add(position, adViewNew);
                return adViewNew;
            } else {
                return adView;
            }
        } else if (row == null || row instanceof AdView) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((SherlockActivity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(viewResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new MyHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);           
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MyHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        holder.textName.setText(items.get(position).getName());

        // more code

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (items != null) {
            return items.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [AdMob policy - Number of ads per page](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en#number)

Comment: @adneal only one ad shows at a time because as you scroll the previous ad goes out of view

Comment: Resuming - What you want to achieve is to have always X items on the screen and one of them always being the ad?

Comment: @nKn I want to have a list where an ad view shows up at every 8th postion. so at position 8 and 16 etc. when I do this, the ad consumes the items that are on my list which i passed to the array adapter at those positions. so at position 8 and 16, i am seeing the ad but i am not seeing what should be at 8 and 16 if the ads were not there. it doesn't push the items down, instead it over writes them

Comment: You're creating the `adView` if `showAd` is `true`. Maybe I'm missing something but inside that `if` condition you're not handling any other `View` related structure, you just inflate the layout if you're not showing the ad (i.e., in the `else` statement), so it's not overwritting them but it's just not created.

Comment: how about defining two different kinds of layouts for your tableview? 1 item, with just the normal content, and one with the adview in addition to the usual content, however you would have to handle the touches on those rows differently than the others.
It might also be an Option to add Dummy entries into your Datasource representing the Ads, then you can handle those dummy entries in getView accordingly. seems like a clean approach

Comment: I would go for having adview in each list item but making it visible only when position is 3

Answer (score 7):

There is more than one way of achieving this. The best way is relying upon the ability of the listView to recycle multiple item types.

In your adapter,

1. getViewTypeCount() - returns information how many types of rows you have in the listView
2. getItemViewType(int position) returns information on which layout type you should use based on the position. That's where your logic of determining the listView objects should go.

There is a good tutorial on how to use [different item types in a list here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296): 
Specifically, look at "Different list items’ layouts".

After that, you need minor arithmetic conversions for your indices so that you map the position to the right place in your data structure (or, you can merge your data structure to include both ad data and item data).

Basically, instead of using items.size() you need to use items.size() + Math.floor(items.size()/NTH_ITEM) and when you get the position, if it's an ad position (position % NTH_ITEM == 0) use a simple conversion like Math.floor(position/NTH_ITEM) to extract from the ad data structure and in similar fashion for your item's structure.

You should rely on the holder pattern of the ListView to reuse your different item view types, like in the tutorial above.

Different approaches, just for the notion, include using something like item wrappers that merge the data source into one and enables differentiating between items by using a type property, like an enum, or a "merging adapter" that merges two specific adapters (this might have a better modularity if you are to include these view types in different lists).

Let me know if you need any help implementing specific parts of this in your use case.

Comment: I support this answer.. I added my own expanding on the same idea below

Comment: Thanks for adding some code for making it rather easy to understand. I have some remarks and commented on it regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Ben Max's answer is cleaner.
It is recommended to use view types when dealing with different types of view.

Here's a good way to do it.

Create a wrapper for your different data types:

```
private class ItemWrapper {
               public static final int TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
               public static final int TYPE_AD = 1;
               public static final int TYPE_COUNT = 2; 

                public ListObject item;
                public AdObject adItem;
                public int type;

                public ItemWrapper(ListObject item) {
                    this.type = TYPE_NORMAL;
                    this.item = item
                }
                public ItemWrapper(AdObject adItem) {
                    this.type = TYPE_AD;
                    this.adItem = adItem;  
                }
}
```

Now come some of the changes to your adapter:

Let's assume you get you initialize your adapter in the constructor

```
 public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<ItemWrapper> mWrappedItems = new ArrayList<ItemWrapper>();
         public void MyAdapter(List<ListObject> items,AdItem adItem){

                for(ListObject item:items){
                    mWrappedItems.add(new ItemWrapper(item));
                }
                //you can insert your ad item wherever you want!
                mWrappedItems.add(2,new ItemWrapper(adItem)); 

            }
}
```

Then a few more changes to your adapter:

```
@Override
   public ItemWrapper getItem(int position) {
      return mWrappedItems == null ? null : mWrappedItems.get(position);
   }
   @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getItem(position).type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        //tells the adapter how many different view types it will need to recycle
        return ItemWrapper.TYPE_COUNT;
    }
```

Now for your getView....
You'll see this is nicer because you can control how your views are inflated

```
public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ItemWrapper item = getItem(position);
        final int type = item.type;
        if (row == null) {
            if (type == ItemWrapper.TYPE_NORMAL) {
                //inflate your normal view layouts
            } else if (type == ItemWrapper.TYPE_AD) {
                //inflate your ad layout
            }
        }

        //now you can easily populate your views based on the type
        if (type == ItemWrapper.TYPE_NORMAL) {
            //get your item data
            final ListObject data = item.item;
            //populate as you would normally
        } else if (type == ItemWrapper.TYPE_AD) {
            final AdItem adItem = item.adItem;
            //populate your ad as needed
        }
        return row;
    }
```

You'll notice that wrapping your data like this gives you great control on how/where your item is display by just manipulating the list instead of doing any weird logic inside your getView(); it also makes it simple to let you inflate layouts according to type and populate them easily. 
I hope this helps!
P.S i wrote a blog entry about this topic before as well:
http://qtcstation.com/2012/04/a-limitation-with-the-viewholder-pattern-on-listview-adapters/

Comment: It's a good example, but some would rather not to mess with their data sources to keep a strong connection and comparability between clientside / server side data. This would also require to save duplicate data or multiple pointers to the same data source, in case you want to keep the originals

Answer (score 1):

I'd go in a different way, instead of adding the ad layout dynamically. Assuming your layout (which is accessed via the `View row` parameter of your `getView()` method) is customized, simply add a `LinearLayout` in it which will be used for the `AdView`.

As you don't want it to be visible on all the rows, mark its visibility to gone by default, but defining it that way will allow you to control your layout and define it how it should be shown.

Assuming this is your layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
  ...>

  <!-- Put here the AdView layout -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adViewLL"
    ... 
    android:visibility="gone" />

  <!-- Add whatever else you need in your default layout -->
  ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Now simply change your `getView()` method to set the visibility to `VISIBLE` whenever you need and put there the `View` for your `AdView`.

```
public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
  MyHolder holder = null;
  boolean showAd = proVersion == false && (position % 8 == k);

  if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((SherlockActivity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(viewResourceId, parent, false);
    holder = new MyHolder();
    holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);           
    row.setTag(holder);

    if (showAd) {
      LinearLayout myAd = (LinearLayout) row.findViewByid(R.id.adViewLL);
      myAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      AdView adViewNew = new AdView((Activity) context, AdSize.BANNER, context.getResources().getString(R.string.adId));
      ...
      myAd.addView(adViewNew);
    }
  } else {
    holder = (MyHolder) row.getTag();
  }

  holder.textName.setText(items.get(position).getName());

  // more code

  return row;
}
```

Comment: That's some major overhead and would degrade the performance of the listview

Comment: Not really if he's using Holders and the initial state of the ad containing `LinearLayout` is gone. All depends on how many rows will he handle, though, but I don't think the performance will be an issue with this approach.

Comment: The performance is slightly degraded (since the AdView is slow and will trigger a re-layout when the ad loads) but it works. I've done it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to nKn's answer my following experience:

1. Encapsulate the Ad view with a ViewSwitcher
2. Show a message where the Ad goes, something like: "a message from our lovely sponsors…"
3. When the Ad callback hits you (onAdLoaded), do a `holder.switcher.setDisplayedChild(1); // if 1 is where your AdView is.`
4. Have a Flag where you can disable Ads so always do if (showAd && adsEnabled) {}, you never know when you might need to disable ads, if you have an API try to retrieve that value from there.
5. #4 can also be used for an else clause: `else {holder.switcher.setDisplayedChild(0);//your generic message}`
6. Have an "AdController" where you determine how often (every what ## of items you want to insert an ad). and have your list ask `if (YourAdController.isAd(position) && adsEnabled) { do the add thing }`

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly a logical error.

Here's an explanation on whats happening.

Going by your description, every 8x position is an ad

Why go on to mess with views or maintaining multiple layouts

In your dataset(i.e the list that you are passing to the adapter) just add an item that indicates its an **ad item** at every **8x** position

So, if its a pro version there's no **ad item** entry in the list

Finally, in your getview

```
if(ad item)
    populate adView
else
    populate regularItemView
```

Hope it simplifies

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on one of the applications that i worked on. here's the approach that worked with me.

- First,you need to create a class that contains your ad details.

  public class AdUnitDetails {
      private String mUnitId;
      private int mIndex;

  ```
  public AdUnitDetails(String mUnitId,int mIndex) {
      super();
      this.mUnitId = mUnitId;
      this.mIndex = mIndex;
  }

  public String getUnitId() {
      return mUnitId;
  }

  public void setUnitId(String mUnitId) {
      this.mUnitId = mUnitId;
  }


  public int getIndex() {
      return mIndex;
  }

  public void setIndex(int mIndex) {
      this.mIndex = mIndex;
  }
  ```

  }
- Then, you create a Sparsearray containing adviews with their positions

  ```
  SparseArray<AdView> mAdViewsMap = new SparseArray<AdView>();
  ```
- Then you need to modify your adapter to receive an arraylist of objects and then you add the ads in their corresponding positions when you fill this list. example(item, item , item , addetails, item, item, etc).
- Then, in your adapter. add the following methods:

  ```
  private static final int TYPE_ITEM= 0;
  private static final int TYPE_AD = 1;
  private static final int TYPES_COUNT = TYPE_AD + 1;

  @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
      return TYPES_COUNT;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if (mItems.get(position) instanceof YourItemClass)
          return TYPE_ITEM;
      else if (mItems.get(position) instanceof AdUnitDetails)
          return TYPE_AD;
  return super.getItemViewType(position);
  }
  ```
- Then, in your `getView()` method,add the following

  ```
      View view = convertView;
      if (mItems.get(position) instanceof YourItemClass) {
          // Handle your listview item view
      } else if (mItems.get(position) instanceof AdUnitDetails) {
          return getAdView(position);
      }

      return view;
  ```
- your `getAdView()` method

  ```
   private AdView getAdView(final int position) {
  if (mAdViewsMap.get(position) == null) {
      AdSize adSize = getAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
      AdView mAdView = new AdView(mContext, adSize, ((AdUnitDetails) mItems.get(position)).getUnitId());
      mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
      mAdViewsMap.put(position, mAdView);
      return mAdView;
  } else {
      return mAdViewsMap.get(position);
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late but here is how i solved mine. 
Converted the current position from int to string ( optional) 
and then every time view is inflated check if position contains (3 || 6 || 9) for that every 3rd visible layout shows an advertisement banner. hope it was helpful will post code if needed :)
 oh and || means "or" if anyone is wondering

Comment: position ends with* sorry typo

Comment: hello @Assassiŋ Shaɖow, I am facing same issue as yours. Please provide the code snippet that will solve your issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code Ashish Kumar Gupta

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adviewlayout); //putting the advertisement banner inside a relativelayout/linearlayout if you want. so that you can make it visibile whenever you want.

    String pos = String.valueOf(position); // converting listview item position from int to string//


    if (pos.endsWith("3")||pos.endsWith("6")||pos.endsWith("9")) {
        // every fourth position will show an advertisement banner inside a listview. here is the proof (0,1,2,advertisement,4,5,advertisement,7,8,advertisement,10,11,12,advertisement,14,15,advertisement,17,18,advertisement,20). did not put advertisements in 0 position cuz its rude to put advertisements in like the first layout in my POV//

        rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else 
    {
        rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

//if its not a 3rd position advertisements will not be shown//
        }
        you are welcome :)